# Perfekt eines Modalverbs in Infinitivsatz

Tags: grammar, past

Es ist möglich, wenn auch nicht schön, zu sagen:

> Ich behaupte, meine Hausaufgaben gemacht haben zu müssen.

Das heißt, dass ich sage, dass ich dazu verpflichtet bin meine Hausaufgaben gemacht zu haben.
Wie sieht es jetzt aus, wenn die Modalität (das Müssen) auch im Perfekt steht?

> Ich behaupte, die Hausaufgaben gemacht haben gemusst zu haben.

- Ist das richtig?
- Ist mein Gefühl richtig, dass es tatsächlich nicht möglich ist, diesen Sachverhalt mittels Infinitivsatz auszudrücken?

Comment: Wenn ich *gemacht haben gemusst* recht schnell hintereinander ausspreche, kommt mir Dein zweiter Satz tatsächlich richtig vor, aber ich kann das gerade nicht weiter untermauern.

Comment: Nein, es müsste dann 'gemacht zu haben gemusst zu haben'  heißen .

Answer (score 2):

Der Kern des Satzes ist

```
Ich behaupte, [...] gemusst zu haben.
```

Zu *was* man genau genötigt war, wird eingeschoben. Das kann z.B. sein:

- `die Hausaufgaben zu machen`, d.h. der Umstand, es zu überhaupt zu tun
- `die Hausaufgaben fertig zu bekommen`, d.h. die Aktion abzuschließen
- `die Hausaufgaben gemacht haben`, d.h. im Zustand zu sein, ein Ergebnis vorliegen zu haben

Letzteres zeigt also, dass der Satz grammatikalisch richtig ist. Es handelt sich um den erweiterten Infinitiv Perfekt.<sup>[(1)](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%BCssen_%28Konjugation%29#Infinitive_und_Partizipien)</sup>

Vereinfacht würde man eher formulieren:

```
Ich behaupte, ich musste die Hausaufgaben erledigt haben.
```